# Реализация с помощью addEventListener

Tags: javascript, html

Столкнулся с проблемой конфликтов JS скриптов.Подсказали что можно реализовать с помощью `addEventListener`.
Как можно реализовать функцию используя `addEventListener` вместо `onclick`?
Заранее спасибо.

Код Кнопки:

```html
<button id="btn-start-recording">START</button>
```

Функция:

```js
  var btn = document.getElementById('btn-start-recording'),
    loader = document.getElementsByClassName('loader')[0];

btn.onclick = function() {
    loader.style.display = 'block'; // показываем .loader
    setTimeout(function() {
      loader.style.display = 'none'; // скрываем .loader
    }, 40000); // задержка перед скрытием в миллисекундах
  }
```

Comment: `btn.addEventListener('click', function(){  });`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('btn-start-recording');

function otherFunction() {
  console.log('function 2');
}

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log('function 1');
});

btn.addEventListener('click', otherFunction);
```

```html
<button id="btn-start-recording">START</button>
```

Пожалуйста, не ленитесь изучать документацию:

- [EventTarget.addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)
- [addEventListener и removeEventListener](https://learn.javascript.ru/introduction-browser-events#addeventlistener-%D0%B8-removeeventlistener)

Answer (score 1):

addEventListener используется следующим образом:

```
var btn = document.getElementById('btn-start-recording');

var firstHandler = function firstHandler() {
    console.log('Первый обработчик');
};

var secondHandler = function secondHandler() {
    console.log('Второй обработчик');        
};

btn.addEventListener('click', firstHandler);
btn.addEventListener('click', secondHandler);
```

Но порядок вызова обработчиков может быть разным, чтобы этого избежать используйте jQuery или аналогичные библиотеки.

Отписаться от обработчиков можно следующим образом:

```
btn.removeEventListener('click', firstHandler);
btn.removeEventListener('click', secondHandler);
```